# How do I convert array of numerics to an integer?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert the following array:

```
2.0.0-p0 :021 > test = 1, 440, 840
 => [1, 440, 840]
```

to the following integer:

```
1440840
```

If I do a `split(',')` and then join them, it works, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use split if it's an Array.  Just do:

```
test.join.to_i
```

Sample run with [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
2.0.0-p195 :007 > t.is_a? Array
 => true 
2.0.0-p195 :008 > t.join.to_i
 => 1440840 
2.0.0-p195 :009 >
```

Comment: To expound a little on this, `#join` does an implicit cast of each element to a string, then joins them together without a delimiter, resulting in a string concatenation of the values in the array. It is then cast back to an integer with `to_i`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
test.inject { |ttl, n| ttl * 1000 + n }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to meditate on:

```
STRING = '1,440,840'

STRING.gsub(',', '').to_i # => 1440840
STRING.tr(',', '').to_i # => 1440840
STRING.delete(',').to_i # => 1440840
STRING.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i # => 1440840

require 'scanf'
STRING.scanf('%d,%d,%d').join.to_i # => 1440840
```

We don't see [`scanf`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/scanf/rdoc/index.html) used much in Ruby, but it's a mainstay in C, and used often in Perl. It's the opposite side of Kernels's [`printf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-printf), [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), [`format`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) and String's [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25).